# x-editable working on anchor tags it hasn't been applied to

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, x-editable

I just realized a few days ago, that on my Foundation Top Bar Section for navigation, some of the links aren't working because somehow they've been taken over by x-editable.

The top navigation and login is handled by Foundation 4 but that php page is included in the overall page.  The main section of the page appears to be working properly.  Obviously, x-editable has not been applied to these anchor tags.  I've searched the main page, product_datax.php, and none of the ids or href values are the same.

```
<section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="left">
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li <? echo $CLASS_data_stats ?>><a href="data_stats">Data Stats</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li <? echo $CLASS_product_datax ?>><a id="product_data" href="product_datax">Product Data</a></li><!--xeditable showing up-->
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li <? echo $CLASS_cat ?>><a id="cat" href="cat">Product Categories</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li <? echo $CLASS_updater ?>><a id="updater" href="updater">Updater</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd abandoned this because it wasn't overwhelmingly important, but just figured it out.  Since my page is populated with table rows, the ids for the various controls are like this: product1...product14.  For those to work in x-editable, the jquery editable code is on anchor tags whose ids start with "product"  The top bar controls happen to start with the same ids and the table controls.